# Rectifying a spark coil that produces 10 kHz

Tags: high-voltage, rectifier, high-frequency

I am working on a project where I want 10 to 30 kV DC (to energize two capacitors in series rated at 28 kV per capacitor). I bought a couple of 25 kV HV rectifiers (one to generate a positive voltage and one to generate a negative voltage) and hooked them up to spark coils.

The first hookup was a couple of motorcycle spark coils and, although I was getting 20 kV P-P into the rectifiers, the rectified voltage was only about 1 kV.

I tried an automotive coil (with a built-in solid-state triggering device and with an external voltage control potentiometer attached) and even though I was getting 20 kV P-P, I still was only getting 1 kV DC through the rectifiers.

After having played with this for such a long time, my conclusion is that my HV rectifiers don't have the frequency response for the 10 kHz signal the automotive spark coil produces. The circuit is so simple this is about the only conclusion I can come to.

The question is: How do I get around this? Are there HV rectifiers available (at reasonable cost) rated at 30 kV and can operate at 10 kHz? Any help in this would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: How do you figure the spark plug coils are generating 10kHz?  Can you post your whole circuit?  As a schematic diagram, that is.

Comment: You can resolve this by using any method you know how to use;  Energy Conversion with losses, Impedance Ratios of a transformer.  You can also sweep an ignition coil beyond 10kHz but you have a tuned circuit with equiv. LC and negative incremental resistance arc. which in near 0 time creates a broad RF spectrum. There is also resistance in carbon wire

Comment: what rectifiers were you using - part number and specification? Some are rated for 50 Hz. Some are rated for much higher frequencies

Comment: What trigger frequency are you using? Although the ringing high voltage frequency of the coils may be on the order of 10kHz your duty cycle may very well be so low that the average DC voltage over a few trigger cycles may very well be much much less than the peak.

Comment: Another thing to think about. Let's say that the in the auto the engine is a four cylinder job and engine RPM is 3600. That calculates out to ((3600/60)*4) = 240 sparks per second. The electronics of the coil trigger circuit may just not let you trigger the spark coil much above that the relatively low frequency. This leads directly to low duty cycle as suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: In terms of the schematic, it is very simple: DC power supply, square wave generator, spark coil that generates 20 KV, 2 high-voltage rectifiers, attached to 2 capacitors in series. I have run across numerous articles on the web about frequency response problems with high-voltage diodes.

Comment: To answer some of these questions I know it's 10 kHz because of an oscilloscope. My square wave generator is operating at hundred hertz with a 10% duty cycle. Playing with frequency and duty cycle has little to no effect on rectification. The spark coil is firing. That's not the issue. The issue is it's not being rectified. The diodes are 2 DL that I got on Amazon and I haven't gotten a response about frequency.

Comment: Since I can't find any specs on the rectifiers and Amazon doesn't answer my queries, I've abandoned these rectifiers and ordered some that I know the specs. And… I'll work from there. Want to thank everybody for answering.